# Converting PHP to the alternative syntax for control structures

Tags: php

Is there an effective way to automatically convert PHP templates from the normal control structure syntax to the alternate syntax?

### From Standard syntax

```
<?php if($a == 5) { ?>
    A is equal to 5
<?php } ?>
```

### To Alternative syntax

```
<?php if ($a == 5): ?>
    A is equal to 5
<?php endif; ?>
```

And obviously include all the other control structures.

Comment: *Sigh* if only there was a "standard" syntax.

Comment: Although I prefer the standard way I'm looking into implementing [Plates](http://platesphp.com/) into an existing project that has lots of templates in the traditional way. If there was an easy way to do it on lots of files then it might make playing around with it nice and simple. According to their [documentation](http://platesphp.com/templates/syntax/) they require the alternative syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [small tool](https://github.com/oranfry/php-syntax-converter) to tackle this problem.

```
cd ~/tools
git clone https://github.com/oranfry/php-syntax-converter.git

# show converted file on screen

cd ~/my-project
cat myfile.php | ~/tools/php-syntax-converter/to-alternative.php

# convert all .php files in the current directory:

cd ~/my-project
find -name '*.php' | while read file; do cat "$file" | ~/tools/php-syntax-converter/to-alternative.php > /tmp/converted.php && mv /tmp/converted.php "$file"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the code itself, than you can use your IDE, `ctrl+f, ctrl+r` in jetbrains, or make macros, or even make your own template generator, but all of this is not an automatically convercion